# Incorrect Display Size For Phonegap Applications

Tags: ios, cordova, size, screen

We are currently developing a phone gap app that will be able to display HTML5 pages. The HTML page consists of a table that is filled up with contents and images. It loads onto the device but the page loaded does not fit on the screen. We have set the HTML elements' width to 100%, but the page still goes out of the screen.

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/index_54-.png','images/index_52.png','images/index_53-.png','images/index-_54.png')">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="dibu"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><a href="index.html" target="neirong" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image4','','images/index_52.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/index_52-.png" name="Image4" width="128" height="117" border="0" id="Image4" /></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="tssd.html" target="neirong" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image5','','images/index_54-.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/index_53.png" name="Image5" width="128" height="117" border="0" id="Image5" /></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image6','','images/index_53-.png',1)"><img src="images/index_54.png" name="Image6" width="128" height="117" border="0" id="Image6" /></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="zxxx.html" target="neirong" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image7','','images/index-_54.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/index_55.png" name="Image7" width="128" height="117" border="0" id="Image7" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Please help, your help will be much apprieciated.

Answer (score 0):

What device are you targeting? You may need to make sure that you've set the width of the body to 100% so the browser explicitly knows the width to make the table, i.e.;

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That will ensure all the table's parent DOM nodes are of a known size and so the table can be rendered properly. Another thing to try is adding a meta tag to your header to make sure the mobile device (I assume thats what you're targeting) is setting the correct display size;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width,  initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1"/>
```

If you know the width your going for you can hard code the screen to that size;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=480,  initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1"/>
```

Probably should use media queries to target your css for the right device (iPhone 3g .v. iPhone 4) etc.